# Replacing rgb value (0,0,0) with (nodata,nodata,nodata) in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, rgb

I have a set of rasters in which I want to replace any rgb value of (0,0,0) with (nodata,nodata,nodata)

I've tried using

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata "0,0,0" in.tif out.tif
```

But this seems to convert all 0s to nodata, for example (0,10,10) becomes (nodata,10,10).  I want these to stay the same and only convert (0,0,0) to (nodata,nodata,nodata).

I'm looking for any solutions using gdal tools like gdal_translate or gdalwarp that I can add into a larger shell script.

Comment: Try gdalwarp with -srcnodata "0,0,0" -dstnodata "0,0,0".

Comment: Thanks but this still seems to replace cells like (0,10,10) with (nodata,10,10).  I need these to stay the same.

Comment: Try if alpha channel works better. And by the way, which GDAL version you have? Should have asked that first.

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-alpha-mask-to-data-value-td5132552.html. Try gdalwarp with warping option  UNIFIED_SRC_NODATA=YES

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the delay.  I was able to solve this (for my purposes) with gdalwarp -srcnodata None -dstnodata None -dstalpha  This seems to hide the (0,0,0) values when viewing in QGIS rather than converting them.